# RTC DS3231 does not loop after initializing

Tags: arduino, initialization, real-time

I'm trying to use the RTC DS3231 - but it does not loop after Initializing in `void setup()`. I only tried the example codes so far:

```
/*
  DS3231: Real-Time Clock. Date Format
  Read more: www.jarzebski.pl/arduino/komponenty/zegar-czasu-rzeczywistego-rtc-ds3231.html
  GIT: https://github.com/jarzebski/Arduino-DS3231
  Web: http://www.jarzebski.pl
  (c) 2014 by Korneliusz Jarzebski
*/

#include <Wire.h>
#include <DS3231.h>

DS3231 clock;
RTCDateTime dt;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  // Initialize DS3231
  Serial.println("Initialize DS3231");;
  clock.begin();
  
  // Set sketch compiling time
  clock.setDateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__);

  // Set from UNIX timestamp
  // clock.setDateTime(1397408400);

  // Manual (YYYY, MM, DD, HH, II, SS
  // clock.setDateTime(2014, 4, 13, 19, 21, 00);
}

void loop()
{
  dt = clock.getDateTime();

  Serial.print("Long number format:          ");
  Serial.println(clock.dateFormat("d-m-Y H:i:s", dt));

  Serial.print("Long format with month name: ");
  Serial.println(clock.dateFormat("d F Y H:i:s",  dt));

  Serial.print("Short format witch 12h mode: ");
  Serial.println(clock.dateFormat("jS M y, h:ia", dt));

  Serial.print("Today is:                    ");
  Serial.print(clock.dateFormat("l, z", dt));
  Serial.println(" days of the year.");

  Serial.print("Actual month has:            ");
  Serial.print(clock.dateFormat("t", dt));
  Serial.println(" days.");

  Serial.print("Unixtime:                    ");
  Serial.println(clock.dateFormat("U", dt));

  Serial.println();

  delay(1000);
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
10:15:16.623 -> Initialize DS3231
```

Does that mean it doesn't work at all? Or that it doesn't continue to loop after calling void setup?

Any help would be appreciated, that can't be that much of a problem..

Comment: is it wired correctly?

Comment: @Juraj yes; sda to pin A4; scl to pin A5

Comment: powering and ground?

Comment: also correct...checked it dozens of times

Comment: Update: I switched from an Arduino Nano to an ESP8266 and sure enough, the RTC works just fine. Just gotta figure out what's the problem with the nano now...

Answer (score 0):

Insert
Wire.begin();
before the clock initializes

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();    
     // Initialize DS3231
          Serial.println("Initialize DS3231");;
          clock.begin();
.
.
.
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).